# loading information from Firebase in a defined order

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am posting some information to Firebase database

```
 let bookObject: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                        "uid": uid,
                    ]         
                    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(key).setValue(bookObject)
```

and I want to retreive the data in a tableView

```
func loadData(){
     if (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser) != nil{

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

           let loggedInUserData = snapshot
        if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            for post in postsDictionary {
                self.posts.add(post.value)
            }
            self.TableView.reloadData()


        }})}
}
```

Which works, however, the posts get loaded to the TableView randomly, sometimes a new post would be posted to the top of the TableView, sometimes it would be posted to the bottom of the TableView. What do I do so that the new post shows on top of the previous cell.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add a timestamp to each post and then sort the posts based on the timestamp. You didn't post how your `TableView` is built, but I recommend using a `tableArray` made of multiple posts that are a custom class `Post` that has all the properties of the post in Firebase. Then you can arrange the posts by doing `tableArray.sort({$0.date > $1.date})`, where date is one of the variables in `Post` containing a String of the timestamp when it was created. You probably want to sort the tableArray right before where you reload the `TableView`'s data.

You can then populate your TableView with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = //dequeueResuableCell

    //retrieve data from the cell's corresponding post
    let postCreator = tableArray[indexPath.row].creatorUID
    let postContent = tableArray[indexPath.row].content
    ...

    //populate the cell using the above data
    ...
}
```

and since your posts in the `tableArray` are in chronological order, the posts in your `TableView` will also be in chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the section called 'Sort data' on this page of Firebase's documentation. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data

It basically allows you to order the result of your query by a child of your choice. In your case you should order by 'date' or 'timestamp' depending on what you store on your Firebase Real-Time database.

Example:

```
// My top posts by number of stars
let myTopPostsQuery = (ref.child("user-posts").child(getUid())).queryOrdered(byChild: "starCount")
```

If when you order by child you still see the new entries coming at the bottom of your tableView, you can simply reverse your array to ensure the newest will come at the top.

```
yourArray.reversed()
```

Hope this helps.